# Struts2 Loading pages asynchronously

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, struts2

I saw [this](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/loading-pages-asynchronously/) video regarding loading pages asychronously through ajax. everything seems simple but what if I want to load a certain page. but before that page load it will do or go to a Certain Action class(let's say populating images) how would I achieve that? I have googled it already but it did not render results

note that I do not want the whole page to load, just a certain div.

Comment: That you're using S2 is irrelevant; call the action, return HTML, load the div. What's the actual issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton I was thinking that I am required to do something classy with my struts2 tags or use a specialized tag for such case. Also that let's say I call a action certain class, on the struts xml it would be mapped to a jsp page, will that jsp page displayed or will that jsp page would be inserted as a fragment in the current page?

Comment: It's happening via JavaScript; it will do whatever you tell it to do.

Comment: Are there any specific code examples? I tried googling and it did not cater my needs.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is yet. There are a million jQuery examples on the web. The back end simply doesn't matter; give jQuery a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 2 doesn't care whether your request is synchronous or asychronous.  This is entirely a client side thing.  You could easily point a page request at the same Struts 2 action as a Ajax request is pointed at, though the returned data might not make sense to your client side application.

Most of the time, your ajax request only wants an HTML fragment, JSON or XML data.  But it could receive a whole HTML page and use some logic to parse it for what it actually needs.  The real difference is that the response to an Ajax request is handled by Javascript logic, whereas a page request is handled by the browser itself when it tries to render a page from the reponse.